# How to visualize the pandas DataFrame with line graph?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that comes with informations, 
`df.info()` prints as following,

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6661 entries, 0 to 6660
Data columns (total 3 columns):
value      6661 non-null float64
country    6477 non-null object
outlier    6661 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 208.2+ KB
None
```

`df.columns.values` prints as following,

```
[u'value' 'country' 'outlier']
```

`df` prints as following,

```
       value country  outlier
0     118.66   CHINA        0
1     120.83   CHINA        0
2      86.83   USA          0
3     112.15   CHINA        0
4     113.60   CHINA        0
5     114.32   CHINA        1
6     111.43   CHINA        0
7     117.22   CHINA        1
8     111.43   CHINA        0

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

6652  420.00     USA        0
6653  420.00     USA        0
6654  500.00     USA        0
6655  500.00     USA        0
6656  390.00     USA        1
6657  450.00     USA        0
6658  420.00     USA        0
6659  420.00     USA        1
6660  450.00     USA        0
```

The value for `1` in the `outlier` column is considered as `outlier` and I would like to visualize the `value` for respective countries w/o considering the `outliers`. I should mentioned, the indexes of the `DF` is not to be considered and I need to put own indexes for the respective countries. To clarify, the DF index of 2 is for the data for the USA `(2 86.83 USA 0)` and it will be the index `zero` data for US. The index 2 data for the `China` will be `(3 112.15 CHINA  0)` and so on.

I was tried to use the code snippet and it didn't work as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot.bar()
df.plot()
plt.show(block=True)
```

How to do that properly ?

Comment: What type of plot are you looking for? there many ways to "visualize the value for respective countries". You must be more specific.

Comment: Please, have a look in the question. I would like to have simple `line graph` with values over the `Y-axis` and the indexes for the respective countries on the `X-axis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first filter values where `outlier` is `1` and then reshape dataframe by [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df[df.outlier == 1]
df['g'] = df.groupby('country').cumcount()

df = df.pivot(index='g', columns='country', values='value')
print (df)
country   CHINA    USA
g                     
0        114.32  390.0
1        117.22  420.0

df.plot()
```

Another solution is `groupby` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df[df.outlier == 1]
df = df.groupby('country')['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack(0)

print (df)
country   CHINA    USA
0        114.32  390.0
1        117.22  420.0

df.plot()
```

Comment: Can we talk little in chat ? I need to ask you something. I partially solved the issue, but still need some modification.